# Syntax for Getting/Setting DataSet Row in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, dataset-designer

Using Microsoft's [How to Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-sql-database-by-using-a-designer?view=vs-2017), I have created a database within a word VSTO project. After this, I used another [How to Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-and-configure-datasets-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) to create a dataset from this database.

Now I am trying to get/set the data in the dataset's tables using the following Syntax from this [Microsoft Concepts Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/typed-vs-untyped-datasets?view=vs-2017):

```
// This accesses the CustomerID column in the first row of the Customers table.
string customerIDValue = northwindDataSet.Customers[0].CustomerID;
```

Using this Syntax, my code is as follows:

```
string employeeName = _SOI_MasterDatabaseDataSet.JobPositionDataTable[0].EmployeeName;
```

This code gets an error saying that '_SOI_MasterDatebaseDataSet.JobPositionDataTable' is a type, which is not valid in the given context. ([Syntax Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM8dw.png))

Here is a screenshot of my [Data Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFaRI.png) as well.

This is the first time I've attempted to use databases/datasets. I'm not sure if this is a syntax error or if I've missed something while setting up the dataset in the Dataset Designer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the code and errors messages.  We don't want pictures of that stuff.

Comment: I don't work with the DataSet designer, but wouldn't it be `_SOI_MasterDatebaseDataSet.JobPosition[0].EmployeeName;`?

Comment: JobPositionDataTable is not an array.  It is a table and you want the first row of the table JobPositionDataTable.Rows[0]

Comment: @jdweng I'm guessing here, but since this is a typed designer, I don't think the Rows collection is necessary.  It's been over 10 years since I had to play with typed sets though.

Comment: With both of these suggestions, I get an error message "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at more Microsoft documentation, I found out I had to initialize the dataSet and dataTable and initialize a tableAdapter to fill the dataTable:

```
_SOI_MasterDatabaseDataSet SOI_MasterDatabaseDataSet = new _SOI_MasterDatabaseDataSet();

SOI_MasterDatabaseDataSet.JobPositionRow newJobPosition = SOI_MasterDatabaseDataSet.JobPosition.NewJobPositionRow();

_SOI_MasterDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.JobPositionTableAdapter jobPositionTableAdapter = new _SOI_MasterDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.JobPositionTableAdapter();

jobPositionTableAdapter.Fill(SOI_MasterDatabaseDataSet.JobPosition);

string positionTitle = SOI_MasterDatabaseDataSet.JobPosition[0].PositionTitle;
string employeeName = SOI_MasterDatabaseDataSet.JobPosition[0].EmployeeName;
```

Here are the additional sources I used: [Edit data in datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/edit-data-in-datasets?view=vs-2017), [Fill datasets by using TableAdapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/fill-datasets-by-using-tableadapters?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Youo should not put "DataTable" to the table name, I suppose:

```
string employeeName = _SOI_MasterDatabaseDataSet.JobPosition[0].EmployeeName;
```